# Three vectors resultant force

Tags: vector-analysis, resultant

Im trying to solve this question.
My question is: should i relocate vector (5N)

[image]

from third quadrant to first quadrant?

Because it is given with its head touching the axis, if i keep it in third quadrant its components (x and y) are going to be both negative.
And if i relocate it to first quadrant, components are going to be positive, which changes the final answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This force diagram doesn't seem right. What point is the $5$ N force being applied to? The question must have specified its direction or provided means to determine it. Where is the question from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, vectors representing forces are assumed, for being added, to have a common origin: you should relocate it in the first quadrant with its origin in 0.

The result is therefore:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&4&+&5 \cos 70° &+&1.5 \cos 120°\\
y&=&0&+&5 \sin 70°&+&1.5 \sin 120° \end{cases}$$